# codeigniter model problem

Tags: codeigniter, model

I updated to CI 2.0 now my models stopped working.I used

```
 parent::__construct();
```

And i defined the class correctly **extends CI_Model** but even using a simple get all

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Returns an error

```
 Call to a member function get() on a non-object in models\crudModel.php on line 13
```

I'm sure its related to the update since they worked fine before.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds very much like you are not loading the database library - have you got it in your config/autoload.php? It is sensible to autoload it if you use the database library in all your controllers:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array( 'database' );
```

Comment: oh wow completely overlooked that part when i replaced the config file thanks